# Câmbio de moeda online

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, mootools

Passei um tempo á procura de um site onde possa fazer cambio de moeda. 
Onde possa fazer pedidos via script do lado do cliente usando um endereço url e receber um objecto JSON com a conversão.

(Acabei por encontrar uma solução que me agrada que coloco aqui.)

Comment: Será que alguma solução pode contemplar o paralelo também? :)

Comment: @bigown, o que é um paralelo?

Comment: Me esqueci do contexto. No Brasil tem cotação do mercado negro. É uma cotação das ruas, não oficial, em geral usada em operações não... aprovadas (vamos dizer assim) pelo governo. É usado em muitas situações. Aqui tem uma taxa conhecida como PTax (média diária das cotações) também, que é oficial. Existem outras situações em que o cálculo não é diário também. É mais complicado obter uma cotação não oficial automaticamente embora seja muito útil. Vai pegar a cotação de quem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão usando [`http://rate-exchange.appspot.com`](http://rate-exchange.appspot.com)

#### Usando jQuery

```js
var fazerRequest = function (valor, origem, destino) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" +
             origem + "&to=" + destino + "&q=" + valor,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#resultado').html(response.v + ' ' + destino);
        }
    });
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/WzXJP/)

---

#### Usando Mootools

```mootools
Request.exchange = new Class({
    Extends: Request.JSONP,
    options: {
        url: 'http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from={from}&to={to}&q={amount}',
        amount: 1
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.setOptions(options);
        this.options.url = this.options.url.substitute(this.options);
        this.parent();
    }
});

var fazerRequest = function (valor, origem, destino) {
    new Request.exchange({
        from: origem,
        to: destino,
        amount: valor,
        onSuccess: function (response) {
            document.id('resultado').set('html', response.v + ' ' + destino);
        }
    }).send();
}
```

Versão Mootools inspirada pelo [*Dimitar*](https://github.com/DimitarChristoff)

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/JbWpU/)

Comment: Marquei esta resposta como "aceite" por ter exemplos de solução do lado do cliente.

Answer (score 7):

Outra opção é utilizar os dados do [banco central europeu](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html#latest).

Eles disponibilizam os dados [nesta url](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml) (atualizada diariamente).

A taxa (atributo *rate*) é baseada no valor do euro. O euro é omitido da lista, mas se estivesse sua taxa seria de valor 1.

Para realizar a conversão basta dividir uma taxa pela outra. Por exemplo:

- Taxa do real (BRL): 3.2091
- Taxa do dólar americano (USD): 1.3776
- Valor de um dólar americano em reais: 3.2091 / 1.3776 = 2.33

Exemplo do XML retornado:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2013-12-16">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3776" />
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="141.87" />
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558" />
            <Cube currency="CZK" rate="27.600" />
            <Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4605" />
            <Cube currency="GBP" rate="0.84385" />
            <Cube currency="HUF" rate="299.77" />
            <Cube currency="LTL" rate="3.4528" />
            <Cube currency="LVL" rate="0.7029" />
            <Cube currency="PLN" rate="4.1758" />
            <Cube currency="RON" rate="4.4570" />
            <Cube currency="SEK" rate="9.0266" />
            <Cube currency="CHF" rate="1.2212" />
            <Cube currency="NOK" rate="8.4345" />
            <Cube currency="HRK" rate="7.6293" />
            <Cube currency="RUB" rate="45.2905" />
            <Cube currency="TRY" rate="2.7970" />
            <Cube currency="AUD" rate="1.5400" />
            <Cube currency="BRL" rate="3.2091" />
            <Cube currency="CAD" rate="1.4579" />
            <Cube currency="CNY" rate="8.3651" />
            <Cube currency="HKD" rate="10.6815" />
            <Cube currency="IDR" rate="16507.61" />
            <Cube currency="ILS" rate="4.8281" />
            <Cube currency="INR" rate="85.0670" />
            <Cube currency="KRW" rate="1450.66" />
            <Cube currency="MXN" rate="17.8013" />
            <Cube currency="MYR" rate="4.4626" />
            <Cube currency="NZD" rate="1.6673" />
            <Cube currency="PHP" rate="60.700" />
            <Cube currency="SGD" rate="1.7293" />
            <Cube currency="THB" rate="44.125" />
            <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="14.2072" />
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

Eles também  ensinam a utilizar [em PHP](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html#dev):

```php
<?php
    function StartElement($parser, $name, $attrs) { 
        if (!empty($attrs['RATE'])) {
            echo "1&euro;=".$attrs['RATE']." ".$attrs['CURRENCY']."<br />"; 
        }
    }
    $xml_parser= xml_parser_create();
    xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "StartElement", "");
    // for the following command you will need file_get_contents (PHP >= 4.3.0) 
    // and the config option allow_url_fopen=On (default)
    xml_parse($xml_parser, file_get_contents ("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"));
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
?>
```

Comment: Sugestão: utilizar o [simplexml_load_file](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-file.php) de PHP.

Comment: Pode adicionar exemplos de aplicação desse url via ajax (lado do cliente)?